# Best Map API for route polygon calculations

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, gis, leaflet

We are building a web app. I need to obtain the area reachable from specific points by driving or by walking in order to obtain the polygon (eg., 5 minutes walking polygon from a specific point), so we can do operations inside (for example, calculating the number of metro stations that get into the area, and many other stuff).

We are considering about leaflet, google maps api, ...  but we are not sure if those solutions cover all our needs.

Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Calculating area?  Sure, Google Maps provides that.  There is the function google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(polygonPoints)

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/133798/115

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for accurate answers (i.e. 5 minute driving distances are dramatically different in different areas and different times. These areas are calculated using calibrated route networks) I would look into using some GIS services to do the number crunching.

[ArcGIS Online](http://www.arcgis.com/features/features.html) is a hosted service and has a JavaScript web mapping API that integrates with their analytics services. It's a paid service, closed source, and not exactly cheap, but they have the market cornered on enterprise GIS and their software is incredibly powerful when used correctly.

If you prefer to roll your own solution look into [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) and pgRouting.